# C# - May I put anything in the brackets? Console.Read()

Tags: c#

I tried to put in the brackets: a, 'a', 0 or 1 but the compiler is protesting.
It looks like that in brackets must not be anything.
What is the purpose of these brackets?

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int n = 0;
            Console.Write("Write a character or number: ");
            n = Console.Read(); // I can't put anything in the brackets
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173114.aspx)

Comment: Some code please, to get better understanding of what you are trying to do

Comment: Google? [MSDN?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Until now I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            
            Console.Write("Write a character or number: ");
            
            n = Console.Read(); // I can't put anything in the brackets

            Console.WriteLine(n);

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Comment: Looking at the docs you can easily see that there is __no overload that takes any parameter__. Read only __returns_- one, namely an `int`. This is so obvious that there most likely is no site that spells it out even more: No. You. Can't. Put. Anything. Between. The. Parenthesis. Even. If. You. Call. Them. Brackets.

Comment: The purpose of the parentheses is to call the function with no parameters, because it doesn't take any parameters.  You should read the documentation on the function to understand what it does, and then you will see why it doesn't take any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read is a method that takes no parameters. To call a method that takes no parameters you still have to include the empty brackets.

Comment: Does it mean, that anything is not allowed in the brackets in any case?

Comment: @prahsC You can not put anything in the brackets when calling Read as it does not accept parameters. Write, however, does accept a parameter which is why you are able to put something in the brackets. Intellisense will indicate when a parameter is expected. Also, as you have discovered, the compiler will indicate when there is a problem. Finally, if in doubt check the documentation on MSDN or by navigating to the Help for any given method.

Comment: &swatsonpicken Thank you for your answers. I've checked the documentation on MSDN and on the other web sides a few times, but I couldn't find such an explicit answer you gave me. I suppose that it is so as you answered, but I just wanted to be sure about it.

Comment: @prahsC You are most welcome. If you found my answer useful then please mark it as the accepted answer.